# Object key values are empty but had data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object, ionic-framework

So I have an object that at certain point gets a value for each key but suddenly loses all the key values.

the key values just get empty and at the console there's a message at the object saying: "this value was evaluated upon first expanding. it may have changed since then", but i dont change is value anywhere else.

My service:

```
image = {
  name: "",
  path: "",
  data: ""
};

async loadFileData(fileNames: string[]) {
    for (let f of fileNames) {
      const filePath = `${IMAGE_DIR}/${f}`;
      const readFile = await Filesystem.readFile({
        directory: Directory.Data,
        path: filePath
      });

      this.images.push({
        name: f,
        path: filePath,
        data: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${readFile.data}`
      });

      // testing
      this.image.name = f;
      this.image.path = filePath;
      this.image.data = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${readFile.data}`;
    }

    console.log('my image: ', this.image);
  }

  async loadFiles() {
    this.images = [];

    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'loading data...',
    });
    await loading.present();

    Filesystem.readdir({
      directory: Directory.Data,
      path: IMAGE_DIR
    }).then(result => {
      this.loadFileData(result.files);
    }, async err => {
      console.log('err: ', err);
      await Filesystem.mkdir({
        directory: Directory.Data,
        path: IMAGE_DIR
      });
    }).then(_ => {
      loading.dismiss();
    });
  }
```

My component:

```
this.photoService.loadFiles();

console.log('my object: ', this.photoService.image);

console.log('is my object empty? ', JSON.stringify(this.photoService.image) === '{}');
```

[my console (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbeJd.png)

Comment: Its original value was `image = { name: "", path: "", data: ""};` .
What you see as `image = { name: "164....", path: "stored...", data: "data..."};` is the value when expanded.

Comment: but since i gave the object keys a value aren't the keys supposed to have that value instead of stay the same as i originally declared it? @qrsngky

Comment: It didn't stay the same, the expanded version is more up-to-date.

Comment: how do I access the expanded values then? i tried logging the values after resolving the function i called so it would be updated but still got the original ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its original value was `image = { name: "", path: "", data: ""};`.
Then you changed it so that it became like `{ name: "164....", path: "stored...", data: "data..."};`

I can make a similar demo, inside the console:
[image]

Then what happens when I press the button to expand?
[image]

Now it shows that data is changed to "whatever" etc., but its original value  `image = { name: "", path: "", data: ""};` is still shown (logged).

The **expanded form** shows the **new** data. The *empty* values belonged to *old* data.

Comment: how do I access the expanded values then? i tried logging the values after resolving the function i called so it would be updated but still got the original ones

Comment: You can simply use `image.data` to get back the updated data, similarly with `image.name` and `image.path`

Comment: but that returns empty

Comment: what is the exact code that returns empty? And where (which position) do you put it?

Comment: looks like for some reason probably because of the asyncs when i called the function on init the value still didn't have been assigned to the object and thats why it was returning as its original declaration

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It about asyn and memory of javascript .

When you run `console.log(this.photoService.image)`

`this.photoService.loadFiles();` is running

Value of this : `{ name: "", path: "", data: ""}`

When you check value of console :

`this.photoService.loadFiles();` finished

memory of `this.photoService.image`  was updated

Value of this => `{ name: "xxx....", path: "yyy...", data: "zzz..."}`